# CSS Breaks after removing .php extenstion in Cpanel using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I removed .php extensions in url using htaccess in Cpanel but after doing that my CSS breaks. I used code below in .htaccess;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^article/used/to/be/here.php$ /article/now/lives/here/ [R=301,L]
```

What Have I missed out.

Comment: You forgot to check your http servers error log output to see what the server actually internally rewrites the css requests to.

Comment: please give me steps on how to check the http servers error log output, I never did it before. Is it on cpanel?

Comment: here is the error output -  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: create full src link in "http://example.com/css/somefile.css"

Comment: Please consider reading more about how to analyze issues with your web environment. You _can not_ program in a web environment without monitoring the http servers error log file _all the time_ . That would be like flying inside a narrow cave - with your eyes blindfolded. Sure, possible, but a very bad idea. Also learn about "rewrite logging". Dive into the official documentation of the apache http server and it's modules. The documentation is, as typical for OpenSource software, of _excellent_ quality and comes with great examples.